# Is a restful service needed to access/update a database?

Tags: database, rest, design-patterns

I have a MySql database set up and a mobile app that should be able to write/read to and from the database.

The data being stored will be posts, comments, votes, etc.

Eventually, I might create a website that uses the same database.

My question is, do I need some sort of middleman (restful) service running or can I just connect straight to the MySql db from the client code (either the mobile app or website)?

Answer (score 2):

Introducing a REST api into the middle would be much beneficial in a lot of ways.

- Improve generalization and reuse. (REST api can be used by both mobile client and web client, no need to do the same work twice)
- Can maintain business logic centrally. (If there's a logic to change or a bug fix, no need to correct in 2 places)
- Can be easily exposed to any other app/client which would need the set of operations provided by the api.
- Extending and maintenance of the app would be much simplified and would take minimum effort.

Answer (score 1):

Especially with the mobile application, where you have much less control of updates, it seems better to use some middle-ware to connect to your database.

Say for instance your website needs a little change in the database that would break an active version of the mobile application. A web service could catch that for you. 
What about a new version of your mobile app that needs a change. Again a web service can handle that for you.

This is all about cutting dependencies and keep the complete ecosystem adaptable.

Whether this is a rest or any other type of web service is a completely different discussion.

Comment: Let's say I do the website first and later add a mobile app. So I would have a web server running that handles routing, reading/writing from the db, delivering html pages, etc.  If I later add a mobile app, would I use the same web server to handle requests from the app?

Comment: Reading and writing from db yes, serving html pages should be in another service.
This way can can more easily reuse the db access service.